# Bootstrap 5.1 How to keep selected tab on pagerefresh

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am trying to keep selected tab active on page refresh. Important - **i'm using bootstrap 5.1**. I checked all the same questions for different versions, none of them worked.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
    </div>
```

There is documentation for tabs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#methods

I'm so sorry i dont know javascript yet but i will be gladness if u help me with this small thing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use js try this xample code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Keep Selected Bootstrap Tab Active on Page Refresh</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="m-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#sectionA" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Section A</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#sectionB" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Section B</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#sectionC" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Section C</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                <h3>Section A</h3>
                <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Section B</h3>
                <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Section C</h3>
                <p>Nullam hendrerit justo non leo aliquet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not working for me with the current Bootstrap version (5.1)...

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to use `BS-5.1 nav pills` with saving active pill id to `Window.localStorage`:

BTW, in Code Snippet `localStorage` doesn't work, so I've created [example in CodePen](https://codepen.io/yaroslav-trach/pen/wvyrJJx?editors=1111):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

```js
const pillsTab = document.querySelector('#pills-tab');
const pills = pillsTab.querySelectorAll('button[data-bs-toggle="pill"]');

pills.forEach(pill => {
  pill.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', (event) => {
    const { target } = event;
    const { id: targetId } = target;
    
    savePillId(targetId);
  });
});

const savePillId = (selector) => {
  localStorage.setItem('activePillId', selector);
};

const getPillId = () => {
  const activePillId = localStorage.getItem('activePillId');
  
  // if local storage item is null, show default tab
  if (!activePillId) return;
  
  // call 'show' function
  const someTabTriggerEl = document.querySelector(`#${activePillId}`)
  const tab = new bootstrap.Tab(someTabTriggerEl);

  tab.show();
};

// get pill id on load
getPillId();
```